# Transcendental numbers and spigot formulae

Tags: number-theory

I thought that one property of transcendental numbers is that to know, say, the millionth decimal digit, you had to know the previous 999,999. Looks like (with e.g. the BBP formula) I'm wrong, that you can discover the millionth digit of pi knowing nothing about the previous ones. Please confirm, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure they have one for decimal, I think the first one was base 16, otherwise you are correct. However, it is still  more work to find out digit 1,000,000 than to find out digit 1.

Comment: @WillJagy : can you make that into an answer?

Comment: @user75124 : the ability to know, say, the millionth digit of $\pi$ in base 16 without knowing all the previous digits, which I think is the BBP formula, is fairly recent, but I don't know a date.  I would guess within the last 10 years.  Hopefully someone will provide one.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect. For instance, you can determine the $n^{th}$ digit of the [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant), which is transcendental without determining the first $(n-1)$ digits.

Comment: thank you! as a follow up, is this (the ability to know the number in the nth position without knowing the previous ones) a fairly recent finding? i.e. until the discovery of spigot formulae?

Comment: @user75124 I don't think this a recent finding. In fact, some transcendental numbers are constructed by explicitly specifying the $n^{th}$ digit. For instance, the Champernowne constant was proposed in $1933$, way before Spigot formulae (I would assume).